# Squid Proxy on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, squid

I have installed Squid 3.5.12 on Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS x64, everything is working fine with blocking everything and allowing a whitelist-only, except for when trying to access a website not on the whitelist, if it's HTTP, I get:

> ERROR The requested URL could not be retrieved

and if it's HTTPS, I get:

> This site can’t be reached

How to get them both display the same message or if possible a custom HTML page?

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour of HTTPS over Proxy is known. The problem was described in [Custom Error Page (deny_info) for HTTPS](https://serverfault.com/a/833028/454297) earlier. Also you can read about it in [No 'access denied' message with 'https'](http://www.squid-cache.org/mail-archive/squid-users/201202/0216.html) (post from squid mailing list).